The limit points of the sequence $x_n=1+\sin\left( \frac{n\pi}{4} \right)$
Consider the sequence
\begin{align}
x_n= 1 + \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{4} \right).
\end{align}
I need to find the limit points of $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$. Notice that
\begin{align}
x_{8n}&= 1 , \\
x_{8n+1} &= x_{8n+3}=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \\
x_{8n+2} &= 2, \\
x_{8n+4}&=1, \\
x_{8n+5}&= x_{8n+7} = 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \\
x_{8n+6}&=0.
\end{align}
Hence, $0,1 \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1,2$ are all limit points.
My question is: Are there limit points of $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$ different from the above listed limit points? (i.e., Is there a subsequence of $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$ with a different limit?). How to ensure this?

Hint: The sequence is periodic since $\sin x = \sin(x + 2k \cdot \pi) = \sin(-x + (2k + 1) \cdot \pi)$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If those are the only five possible values in the sequence and each occurs infinitely often then they are the only possible limit points

@Hussein Eid Do you mind telling me why you have deleted your question after I have written an answer?

Excuse me, I deleted it by mistake. I can't undo the deletion. I am so sorry.
